# Datastax Java driver 4.6.1 unable to override configurations with application.conf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax

I have created application.conf in my src.main.resources folder:

```
datastax-java-driver {
  basic {
    request {
      default-idempotence = true
      timeout = 5
    }
  }
  advanced {
    connection {
      max-requests-per-connection = 32767
    }
  }
}
```

These are just some test properties, and I don't think these properties are being applied because when I poke around in the debugger the defaults are unchanged.

Any ideas what could be going on or how I can check if the custom properties are being applied?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Maven then you've placed it correctly in the `src/main/resources` folder. Otherwise, it needs to go in the application classpath.

Answer (score 1):

@ThatHansel,

Could you show the output similar to the below to understand what values you get from your program?

I've a sample class leveraging DataStax Java Driver `4.9.0` and I am printing the values. I am using the defaults here for this demonstration.

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.DefaultDriverOption;

public class DriverConfigsDemo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
    try (CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder().addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9042))
        .withLocalDatacenter("dc1").build()) {// update to match your environment
        System.out.println("Driver Configs - Idempotence: " + session.getContext().getConfig().getDefaultProfile().getString(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_DEFAULT_IDEMPOTENCE));
        System.out.println("Driver Configs -     Timeout: " + session.getContext().getConfig().getDefaultProfile().getDuration(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_TIMEOUT));
    }
    }
}
```

and when I run this program I get the below and you should also see something *similar* in your case (i.e. idempotence being *true* & timeout being *PT5S*),

```
09:56:10.019 [main] INFO  c.d.o.d.i.c.DefaultMavenCoordinates - DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.9.0
09:56:10.574 [s0-admin-0] INFO  c.d.o.d.internal.core.time.Clock - Using native clock for microsecond precision
Driver Configs - Idempotence: false
Driver Configs -     Timeout: PT2S
```